# Ruby & Savon SOAP client - Unable to find SOAP operation

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap, wsdl, savon

First time working with a SOAP client, so not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's the SOAP API I'm trying to use: http://services.carsolize.com/BookingServices/DynamicDataService.svc?wsdl

```
irb(main):018:0> client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://services.carsolize.com/BookingServices/DynamicDataService.svc?wsdl", convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase)
```

No matter what I pass to `call` on `client`, it tells me:

```
irb(main):022:0> client.call :service_request, :message => {}
HTTPI GET request to services.carsolize.com (net_http)
Savon::UnknownOperationError: Unable to find SOAP operation: :service_request
Operations provided by your service: []
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:22:in `ensure_exists!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:14:in `create'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb:32:in `operation'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb:36:in `call'
    from (irb):22
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I understand that the SOAP service isn't reporting any operations. Is there any way around this? Is it something on my side that's messing it up, or is it the web service?

Savon version: 2.2.0

Comment: The best way to investigate your service is to use SoapUI and to create calls that work. The next step would be to write a client in Ruby/Savon which creates the same request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Savon 2.x.x can access a Web Service without a WSDL.
I inspected the WSDL you provided with SoapUI and used the output to create the following code snipped.

It doesn't work because I obviously haven't the correct credentials but it should give you the idea where to continue.

```
#!ruby
#
gem 'savon', '~> 2.0'
require 'savon'

client = Savon.client(
    endpoint: 'http://services.carsolize.com/BookingServices/DynamicDataService.svc',
    soap_action: "http://tempuri.org/IDynamicDataService/ServiceRequest",
    namespace: 'http://tempuri.org/',
    convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase,
    env_namespace: :soapenv,
    namespace_identifier: :tem,
    log: true,
    log_level: :debug,
    pretty_print_xml: true
)

response = client.call(:service_request,
                       message: {
                          'tem:rqst' => {
                            'BookAsUser' => 'nobody',
                            'Credentials' => {
                              'Password' => 'super secret',
                              'UserName' => 'JoeSixpack'
                            },
                            'Request' => {
                              'ClientIP' => '192.168.142.857'
                            },
                            'RequestType' => 'reservation',
                            'SessionID' => 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBB',
                            'TypeOfService' => 'speedy'
                          }
                       }
                      )
 p response.to_hash
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this tomorrow and report back. Thanks so much!

Comment: Here's what I got when I tried that code (with valid credentials)

`Savon::SOAPFault: (a:ActionNotSupported) The message with Action 'ServiceRequest' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a C       ontractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between s       ender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the        same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).`

Comment: Here we go again: I found a spelling error in the namespace definition. I also found using SoapUI that there is a custom SOAPAction necessary. I edited the source in my answer accordingly. Now I still get an error because my fantasy RequestType is unknown. I hope you'll have description of the service and know what to put in?

Comment: I think that got me past the initial issue about Savon actually building the request instead of giving me an error. I think it actually uncovered a different issue that I didn't realize was there. There's an issue with DNS resolution on my VM that I'll need to track down (which may actually have solved the initial issue as well, stupid me.)

Comment: Looks like the DNS resolution issue didn't change the original error I was getting prior to your answer. Still getting that ActionNotSupported error. I'll keep at it.

Comment: Found out my DNS failure was specific to yesterday (power outage caused my server to go down and it didn't reboot properly). Thanks for all your help Seteffen.

Comment: For later Savon (v. 2.3.3), `:soap_action` can only be a local, not global, option. Therefore, it must be removed from the call to `Savon.client` and added as an option in `client.call`.