# Ruby(2.0) & Savon(2) SOAP client - returning nil SOAP operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to integrate my rails app with SOAP based web-service.
Being a novice in SOAP, I referred [this](http://savonrb.com/version2/) to get started.

My First step was to create a client using Savon:
`client = Savon.client(wsdl: "https://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/Reg/ABCRegService.svc?wsdl")`

Now, when I do `client.operations`, I get a `[]`

The wsdl looks something like this(I have masked value fields for security)

```
<wsdl:definitions name="some_name" targetNamespace="some_targetNamespace">
<wsdl:import namespace="some_Namespace1" location="some_nameService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="some_targetNamespaceImports">
        <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://example.net/some_name/some_Service.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="some_targetNamespace"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="some_name_RegisterTool_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RegisterTool"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="some_name_RegisterTool_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RegisterToolResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="UnregisterToolRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UnregisterToolRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="UnregisterToolRequest_Headers">
    <wsdl:part name="AuthenticationHeader" element="tns:AuthenticationHeader"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="UnregistrationResult">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UnregistrationResult"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType msc:usingSession="false" name="some_name">
    <wsdl:operation name="RegisterTool">
        <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="some_targetNamespacesome_name/RegisterTool" message="tns:some_name_RegisterTool_InputMessage"/>
        <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="some_targetNamespacesome_name/RegisterToolResponse" message="tns:some_name_RegisterTool_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UnregisterTool">
        <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="some_targetNamespacesome_name/UnregisterTool" name="UnregisterToolRequest" message="tns:UnregisterToolRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="some_targetNamespacesome_name/UnregisterToolResponse" name="UnregistrationResult" message="tns:UnregistrationResult"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:service name="some_name">
    <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_some_name" binding="i0:WSHttpBinding_some_name">
        <soap12:address location="https://example.net/Dcsome_name/some_nameService.svc"/>
        <wsa10:EndpointReference>
            <wsa10:Address>https://example.net/Dcsome_name/some_nameService.svc</wsa10:Address>
            <Identity>
                <Dns>localhost</Dns>
            </Identity>
        </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

</wsdl:definitions>

I looked into similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422639/ruby-savon-soap-client-unable-to-find-soap-operation). When I tried creating client in the suggested manner

```
client = Savon.client(
  endpoint: 'proper_endpoint',
  soap_action: "proper_soap_action",
  namespace: 'proper_namespace',
  convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase,
  env_namespace: :soapenv
)
```

I got:

> :in `method_missing': Unknown global option: :soap_action (Savon::UnknownOptionError).

Any Ideas on how to get through this?

Environment:

- OS:Windows 7(Installed rails using RailsInstaller)
- Ruby version: 2.0.0
- Savon: 2
- Rails 4.1.8

> Update:
> I tried hitting the same WSDL from SOAPUI.
> To make it work in SOAPUI,
> I had to

- set `WS-Addressing` property to `true`,
- Check the checkbox for `Add default wsa:to`,
- Use `<![CDATA[]>` to pass identifiers parameters.

Any leads on how to set these things in while creating Savon client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to incorrect parsing of WSDL. In the wasabi gem, lib/parser.rb on line 136, the current XPATH search is:

```
wsdl:definitions/wsdl:binding/wsdl:operation', 'wsdl' => WSDL
```

However, the WSDL I am referring has elements organised differently and I had to tweak the above line to:

```
'wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType/wsdl:operation', 'wsdl' => WSDL
```

Here is a link for the same issue in github: https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/702

Answer (score 1):

Your process of retrieving operations of the wsdl is perfectly right. I checked the wsdl in 'Soap UI' & it seems like that the WSDL has some error. And this is why you are not getting any operations as the wsdl is not providing any definition.

```html
Error loading [https://xx.xxxx.xxx/DcRegistration/DCRegistrationService.svc?wsdl=wsdl0]: 
java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream
```

Comment: But when I tried it using SOAPUI(read the updated part), as suggested by you, I am able to hit the service and get proper response.